# Connecting a php application to a local file structure

Tags: php

Is there a way to connect an online php application to a local file structure through user input so the application can acces folders and files locally?

Comment: Are you trying to hack everyone who enters your site?

Comment: No, but I'm assuming the answer is no.

Comment: client-side *Javascript/FileReader* or *ActionScript/FileReference*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no there is no way of doing this using only PHP. Not unless you have the user to run a local web server with PHP support. If there was a way, then what would stop people from creating websites only for the purpose of hacking users?

Browsers can access local FS only using an embeded control such as Java applet. Applets can be signed (just like Windows programs), and thus have less restrictive security as long as the user will trust your applet's signature.

Comment: I see. Is there a tutorial out there that can provide instruction in doing this?

Comment: Doing what? Writing a Java applet? Or running a local web server?

Comment: Writing a java applet.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. Google is your friend.